# Case being skipped and sent to catch?

Tags: java, string, tokenize

When running this code case 6 is being skipped and sent to the catch statement.

The user is supposed to enter his/her in put all on one line ( Ex. 6 4 10 ENTER) and then the numbers are supposed to be split by the StringTokenizer and then added in the while statement, But instead is sent to the catch printing the statement.

Included below is my consoleReader class to explain what it does and what exceptions are thrown by it, as well as my case 6 from my program.

```
  case 6:
                        System.out.println("Enter your numbers all on one line then press enter");
                        String pnum = console.readLine();

                        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(pnum);

                        double sum = 0;
                        while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
                            double num = Double.parseDouble(pnum);
                            sum = num + num;
                        }
                        mathOut = String.valueOf(sum);

                    break;
            }
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Your number was incorrect, please try again, enter \"E\" to exit or enter to continue.");
                String continueOrQuit = console.readLine();

                if(continueOrQuit.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
                    done = true;
                }else{
                    done = false;
                }
```

ConsoleReader:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

/** 
   A class to read strings and numbers from an input stream.
   This class is suitable for beginning Java programmers.
   It constructs the necessary buffered reader, 
   handles I/O exceptions, and converts strings to numbers.
*/

public class ConsoleReader
{  /**
      Constructs a console reader from an input stream
      such as System.in
      @param inStream an input stream 
   */
   public ConsoleReader(InputStream inStream)
   {  reader = new BufferedReader
         (new InputStreamReader(inStream)); 
   }

   /**
      Reads a line of input and converts it into an integer.
      The input line must contain nothing but an integer.
      Not even added white space is allowed.
      @return the integer that the user typed
   */
   public int readInt() 
   {  String inputString = readLine();
      int n = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
      return n;
   }

   /**
      Reads a line of input and converts it into a floating-
      point number. The input line must contain nothing but 
      a nunber. Not even added white space is allowed.
      @return the number that the user typed
   */
   public double readDouble() 
   {  String inputString = readLine();
      double x = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
      return x;
   }

   /**
      Reads a line of input. In the (unlikely) event
      of an IOException, the program terminates. 
      @return the line of input that the user typed, null
      at the end of input
   */
   public String readLine() 
   {  String inputLine = "";

      try
      {  inputLine = reader.readLine();
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {  System.out.println(e);
         System.exit(1);
      }

      return inputLine;
   }

   private BufferedReader reader; 
}
```

Comment: You only enter the `catch` if an exception of those that the catch gets has been thrown. Review the stacktrace.

Comment: If something is "sent to `catch` instead of a `case 6:`", it means that you've got an exception before the program gets to `case 6:`.

Comment: Thats the thing it should not have gone to the catch at all.

Comment: So call a `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch, so you can see what the exception is, where it came from, etc.

Comment: there is already a class that "reads strings and numbers from an input stream" called `Scanner`.

Comment: Case six is entered, then once the input is taken in it is sent to the catch @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to convert the original String input not the tokens:

Change this:

```
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
                        double num = Double.parseDouble(pnum);
                        sum = num + num;
                    }
```

By this:

```
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
    double num = Double.parseDouble(token);
    sum += num;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! thanks so much, i shouldve realized this.